# Знаки препинания в сложном предложении (2)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания в предложении **"Получите ли вы удовольствие от практики или первая попытка станет последней, целиком зависит от качества вашей подготовки."**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Предлагаемое решение**

**Получите ли вы удовольствие от практики или первая попытка станет последней –  (это) целиком зависит от качества вашей подготовки.** (Нет паузы и запятой).

Сравнить: **От вас зависит, получите ли вы удовольствие от практики, или первая попытка станет последней**. (Пауза и запятая).

**Пояснение**

1) Розенталь: Тире ставится для интонационного отделения главной части сложноподчиненного предложения от придаточной: **Ответила ли она на его письмо или нет — он так и не узнал. Голова ли думает, сердце ли чувствует или руки перевёртывают стаканы — всё покрывается равными плесками** (Г.);

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=142#pp142

2) Это тоже Розенталь: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=139#pp139

**Трудно было понять, наступают ли это сумерки, или это тучи так непроницаемо окутали землю** (Баб.). Следовательно, запятая перед ИЛИ не ставится, если ЛИ...ИЛИ соединяют однородные члены предложения, и ставится, если они соединяют части предложения.

3) Комментарий

Приведенные примеры противоречат друг другу, следовательно, требуется учитывать другие факторы, в частности позицию придаточных и смысловые отношения между придаточной и главной частью.

Тире обычно ставится, когда придаточное или однородные  придаточные находятся **в препозиции.**

Тогда можно предположить, что при постановке тире мы должны **объединить придаточные предложения и противопоставить их главной части,   но тогда  запятая  и наличие паузы будут препятствовать этому.**

Answer (score 0):

Два однородных придаточных при общем главном предложении. Но в этом случае союз ЛИ... ИЛИ рассматривается как повторяющийся, запятая перед ИЛИ ставится:  *"Получите ли вы удовольствие от практики, или первая попытка станет последней, целиком зависит от качества вашей подготовки."*

В конструкциях с союзом «ли/ль… или» действуют следующие пунктуационные правила.

Запятая перед «или» не ставится, если «ли/ль… или» соединяют однородные члены предложения («ли/ль… или» в данном случае не образуют повторяющегося союза).

*Чувствительные дамы ахали от ужаса; мужчины бились об заклад, кого родит графиня: белого ли или черного ребенка. А. Пушкин, Арап Петра Великого. От света ли электричества или от волнения она слегка порозовела и кажется моложе. Л. Андреев, Христиане.*

Запятая перед «или» ставится, если «ли/ль… или» соединяют части сложносочиненного предложения, в том числе вопросительного («ли/ль… или» в данном случае рассматриваются как повторяющийся союз).

*Плохо ли вам было у Плюшкина, или, просто, по своей охоте гуляете по лесам да дерете прохожих? Н. Гоголь, Мертвые души. Во сне ль всё это снится мне, // Или гляжу я в самом деле, // На что при этой же луне // С тобой живые мы глядели? Ф. Тютчев, Опять стою я над Невой... Идет ли дождь, или светит солнце – ему всё равно.*

**Запятая перед «или» ставится, если «ли/ль… или» соединяют однородные придаточные предложения («ли/ль… или» в данном случае также рассматриваются как повторяющийся союз).**

*Я девять лет не видал своей маменьки и не знал, жива ли она, или кости ее лежат уже в сырой земле.* Л. Толстой, Отрочество.[ЛИ... ИЛИ. Грамота.ру](http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_392)

Comment: А запятая перед *целиком* не обсуждается? Почему-то очень хочется поставить тире, как перед словом *это* или перед обобщающим словом.

Comment: По-моему *ли* в данном случае играет роль союзной частицы,   присоединяющей придаточное, а не "двойника" союза *или*, поэтому запятая перед *или* не нужна.

Answer (score 0):

По-моему *ли* в данном случае играет роль союзной частицы, присоединяющей придаточное, а не "двойника" союза или, поэтому правило о повторяющихся союзах здесь не работает.

**Получите ли вы удовольствие от практики или первая попытка станет последней, целиком зависит от качества вашей подготовки.**

Сравните:

*Получите ли вы удовольствие от практики, или первая попытка станет последней — это ничего не меняет.*

Здесь повторяющиеся союзы.